# Using if/else statement with time to change an objects class

Tags: javascript, html, css, datetime, if-statement

I want to be able to determine the class of an object depending on the time - I currently have two classes, `recommendedspot` and `notrecommended`. I have tried the code below however the image does not appear as I would like.

Below is my code:

```js
var time = new Date().getHours();
if (time > 9 && time < 17) {
  document.getElementById("spotsouth").classList.remove('notrecommended');
  document.getElementById("spotsouth").classList.add('recommendedspot');
} else if (time > 6 && time < 9) {
  document.getElementById("spotnorth").classList.remove('notrecommended');
  document.getElementById("spotnorth").classList.add('recommendedspot');
} else if (time > 17 && time < 21) {
  document.getElementById("spotnorth").classList.remove('notrecommended');
  document.getElementById("spotnorth").classList.add('recommendedspot');
} else {}
```

```css
.notrecommended {
  display: none;
}

.recommendedspot {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 15px;
  max-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<img id="spotsouth" src="site-logo.png" alt="spot south" class="notrecommended">
<img id="spotnorth" src="site-logo.png" alt="spot north" class="notrecommended">
```

If anyone knows where I have gone wrong, please let me know as I can't seem to figure it out! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Incidentally, you could greatly reduce the amount of code you need. Any time you find yourself writing repetitive, nearly-identical code, always assume there's a better way. Cache the element into a variable to save all those repeated `document.getElementById(...` lines, and merge cases where they end up adding/removing the same class by adding multiple cases to your conditionals.

Comment: "I have tried the code below however the image does not appear as I would like". Please specify, how would you like it to work?

Comment: Are you calling the function everyhour? You need to use setTimeout to schedule it every hour otherwise it will run only once.

Comment: Well if it's 5PM, your if conditions will never be truthy because you have `<` and `>` but no equality test. Add an `<=` or `>=` or both where it makes sense.

Comment: @beerwin By that I mean that the image does not appear at all.

Comment: @luke111 when _exactly_ the images should be shown / hidden?

Comment: @luke111 see my answer based on _assumptions_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, as others have emphasized, that the comparisons are not what you want. Also, half of the logic is missing: when you recommend something in one time slot, you'll have to remove in another, if you don't wish to show it.

This is a testable solution with, easier to understand, code.

You can test this by replacing the `new Date.getHours()` with actual numbers, to see how it changes.

```js
function promote(element) {
  element.classList.remove('notrecommend');
  element.classList.add('recommendedspot');
}

function demote(element) {
  element.classList.remove('recommendedspot');
  element.classList.add('notrecommend');
}

function processElements(time) {
  var southSpot = document.getElementById("spotsouth")
  var northSpot = document.getElementById("spotnorth");

  var inMorning = time >= 6 && time < 9;
  var inWorkTime = time >= 9 && time < 17;
  var inEvening = time >= 17 && time <= 21

  if (inWorkTime) {
    promote(southSpot);
    demote(northSpot);
  } else if (inMorning || inEvening) {
    promote(northSpot);
    demote(southSpot);
  } else {
    // this part of the code depends on what would you like to happen outside the
    // known time slots (this one hides both elements, but any other combination
    // is possible)
    demote(southSpot);
    demote(northSpot);
  }
}

processElements(new Date().getHours());

// test with actual numbers: 1, 6, 8, 9, 12, 17, 19, 21 for example to see how it changes:
// processElements(1);
```

```css
.notrecommended {
  display: none;
}

.recommendedspot {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 15px;
  max-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<img id="spotsouth" src="site-logo.png" alt="spot south" class="notrecommended">
<img id="spotnorth" src="site-logo.png" alt="spot north" class="notrecommended">
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not handle the times properly do it something like below :-

```
`var time = new Date().getHours();
 if (time >= 9 && time < 17) {
   document.getElementById("spotsouth").classList.remove('notrecommended');
   document.getElementById("spotsouth").classList.add('recommendedspot'); 
 } else if (time > 6 && time < 9) {
   document.getElementById("spotnorth").classList.remove('notrecommended');
   document.getElementById("spotnorth").classList.add('recommendedspot');
 } else if (time >= 17 && time < 21) {
   document.getElementById("spotnorth").classList.remove('notrecommended');
   document.getElementById("spotnorth").classList.add('recommendedspot');
} else {}`
```

handle the time i.e. equal to 6 ,17 , 9

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You have not handled the equalities i.e when your time is 6/9/17/21.Handling the equalities resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using javascript `case` with only one `html` element. It simply provides the proper image at a given time. Also handles time frames outside the given logic (night time?)...

**update** added an alternate `switch` as some folks consider `switch (true)` bad behaviour. The alternate first determines the proper timeframe.

```js
var imgNorth = 'url/to/north.png';
var imgSouth = 'url/to/south.png';
var imgClose = 'url/to/close.png';

var image  = document.getElementById("image");
var image2 = document.getElementById("image2");

var time = new Date().getHours();

/* Solution */

switch (true) { // conditional switch, some folks don't like this
   case (time >=  6 && time <   9): // Between 6 and 9
   case (time >= 17 && time <= 21): // Between 17 and 21
       image.src = imgNorth;
       image.alt = 'spot north';
       break;

   case (time >= 9 && time < 17): // Between 9 and 17
       image.src = imgSouth;
       image.alt = 'spot south';
       break;

   case (time < 6 || time > 21): // ??
       image.src = imgClose; // No seats? closed? stand only??
       image.alt = 'closed';
       break;
};


/* Alternate */

// Get timeframe
var timeFrame =  (time >=  6 && time <   9) ? 1 :
                ((time >= 17 && time <= 21) ? 2 :
                ((time >=  9 && time <  17) ? 3 : 4 ));                 

switch (timeFrame) { // fall-through switch check, preferred
    case 1:
    case 2: // Between 6 and 9 or between 17 and 21
        image2.src = imgNorth;
        image2.alt = 'spot north';
        break;

    case 3: // Between 9 and 17
        image2.src = imgSouth;
        image2.alt = 'spot south';
        break;

    case 4: // ??
        image2.src = imgClose; // No seats? closed? stand only??
        image2.alt = 'closed';
        break;
};
```

```html
<img id="image" src="site-logo.png" alt=""><br>
<img id="image2" src="site-logo.png" alt="">
```